# Modifying stim simulator state by resetting the current inverse tableau not working as desired?

Tags: stim

My goal is to run the Clifford simulation in stim where I apply Clifford gates (not neccesarily listed in the “named gates” list) e.g., random 2-qubit Clifford gates with tableau given by stim.Tableau.random(2). To do this I apply 2-qubit gates to some chosen qubits (by getting the current tableau from the simulator, appending it and resetting the simulator tableau to the new value). For testing I run the following code which simply should create a Bell state (apply H to the 0th qubit and then CNOT with control on the 0th and target on the 1st qubit):

Code:

```
s = stim.TableauSimulator()

s.set_num_qubits(2)

cnot=stim.Tableau.from_named_gate("CNOT")

h=stim.Tableau.from_named_gate("H")

print(np.abs(s.state_vector()))

print(s.current_inverse_tableau())

tab=s.current_inverse_tableau()

tab.append(h**(-1),[1]) #equiv to Hadamard on the 0th qubit due to little endian convention

s.set_inverse_tableau(tab)

print("H added",1) 

print(np.abs(s.state_vector()))

tab=s.current_inverse_tableau()

print(tab)

tab.append(cnot**(-1),[1, 0]) #CNOT on the 0th qubit

s.set_inverse_tableau(tab)

tab=s.current_inverse_tableau()

print("CNOT added",[1,0])

print(tab)

print(np.abs(s.state_vector()))
```

Output:

```
[1. 0. 0. 0.]

+-xz-xz-

| ++ ++

| XZ __

| __ XZ

H added to 1

[0.70710677 0.         0.70710677 0.        ]

+-xz-xz-

| ++ ++

| XZ __

| __ ZX

CNOT added to [1, 0]

+-xz-xz- #tableau modified

| ++ ++

| XZ _X

| _Z ZX

[0.70710677 0.         0.70710677 0.        ] #but state unchanged???
```

The above gives unexpected result of CNOT not affecting the state created in the previous step (despite the corresponding tableau changed).

I contrast it with the following expected behavior

Code:

```
s = stim.TableauSimulator()

s.set_num_qubits(2)

s.h(1)

print(np.abs(s.state_vector()))

s.cnot(1,0)

print(np.abs(s.state_vector()))
```

Output:

```
[1. 0. 0. 0.]

H added to 1

[0.70710677 0.         0.70710677 0.        ]

CNOT added to [1,0]

[0.70710677 0.         0.         0.70710677]
```

What am I missing and how to convince stim to produce a desired output in the first case as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **prepend** the inverse operation instead of appending the operation, because it's the inverse tableau.

In stim v1.9+ you can use [`stim.TableauSimulator.do_tableau`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.TableauSimulator.do_tableau) instead of manually applying the tableau like you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense and it seems to work!